# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer loads pdf after click or scrolling

Tags: angular, delay, loading, jspdf, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Frequently the PDF files are displayed after a long wait. However, they are rendered immediately if you're scrolling or click.
I am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer with angular.

What to do in order to fix this ?

<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
[src]="'assets/pdfs/sample.pdf'" [height]="'73vh'" [useBrowserLocale]="true">

It's documented here:

https://www.pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/page-view-mode

Comment: Your syntax is fine. Share rest of the code so we could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. I know the bug you're describing and I'm still trying to solve it (see [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/1316)), but I've managed to implement a workaround, so the delay is down to a fraction of a second.